# Get quantile of column only if value of another column satisfies condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantile

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I want to a "double sort" where within the lowest 50%ile of column A, I extract the lowest 50%ile of column B.

```
A      B
3     1.0
5     2.0
7     0.5
9     2.1
```

In this example, the 50th percentile  of A would give me the first two rows. Then, the 50th percentile of B of those two would be 1.5. Thus I should return something like column C:

```
A      B     C
3     1.0    True
5     2.0    False
7     0.5    False
9     2.1    False
```

In this manner, it is important that the third row does not become true.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you just want the C column that states whether the row for column A and B are both below the 50th percentile?

Comment: Not quite; I want to find where column A is below the 50th percentile. Out of this subset of rows, I want to find the percentile of column B on this new subset only, completely ignoring the values where A is above the 50th percentile. I'll edit for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
(
    df.assign(C=df.A.lt(df.A.quantile(0.5)))
    .assign(C=lambda x: x.C & x.B.lt(x.loc[x.C].B.quantile(0.5)))
)

    A   B   C
0   3   1.1 False
1   5   0.9 True
2   7   2.0 False
3   9   2.1 False
```

The first assign creates a flag to indicate whether A is below 50% quantile.

The second assign does 2 things:

1. Check if B is below the 50% quantile of the subset of B filtered by
   first condition
2. Do a logical AND of the flag(C) and the results of step 1 above and update column C.

Comment: This works , thank you. However, can you please explain what's going on in the second assignment? I'm finding it difficult to follow and I'd like to understand why it works so I can recreate this on my own wothout copy/paste.